# mysql DELETE query failing, using implode IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, implode

I am currently populating an array with checkboxes, imploding the array variable and using that variable in an IN clause within a DELETE function.  var_dump is showing that I am creating a correct query, yet I can't get any deletion to occur.  This is a new approach to an existing problem I have had for a month or so.

Here's what I have.

```
//Connect to the db
$id_array = NULL;

// Make the query to display user's uploads
 $q = "SELECT upload_id, title, genre, length, created, views
        FROM upload
        WHERE owner_id =". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."
        ORDER BY title ASC";


$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query

if($r)
    {
        // If it ran okay, display the records
        echo '<table align="center"
            cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"
            width="75%">
           <tr><td align="left"><b>Title</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Genre</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Pages</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Submitted</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Views</b></td>
           </tr>';

        // Fetch and print all the records:
?><form action="/nbproject/newwriter_profile.php" method="post">
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
       echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
       $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
       . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
       . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
       . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
       . $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">' //. var_dump($row) //dump row value for testing
       . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value= "'.$row['upload_id'].'"'.' />'.' </td>'. '</tr>';
    }
   echo '</table>'; // Close the table
        ?>
```

the above code creates a simple table, each record is shown with a corresponding checkbox, check to delete then click "Delete"

```
         <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" align="right"/> 
       </form>

<?php
   } // End of if ($r) IF.
    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection
```

custom delete function:

```
function submit_delete() {
  if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox'])) { //Check to see if a delete command has been submitted.
    //This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
    //You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
   // var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
    $id_array = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $id_array = array_map('intval', $id_array);
    $id_array = array_unique($id_array);
    $id_array = implode(',',$id_array);
    //var_dump($id_array);
    deleteUploads($id_array);

  }
  else {
    echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";//var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
  }
}

$delete_success = false;
function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
    require_once(my connection to db);

    mysqli_free_result($r);

  if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; echo 'wtf'; }

  //var_dump($id_array);
```

above var dump shows correct id's as shown in my mysql database

```
    $gone = "DELETE  FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN ("."$id_array".")";
    var_dump($gone);
```

above var verifies that the query is formed correctly, with comma separated id's

```
    $goodbye = mysqli_query($dbc, $gone);

    if ($goodbye) { $delete_success = true; var_dump($delete_success);}
    else { $delete_success = false;}
    var_dump($delete_success);
```

above var dump shows bool false

```
    //mysqli_close($dbc);
    if($delete_success == true) { echo 'done';
    header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else
      {
    echo "Error b/c delete failed";
```

the above echo shows after checking any number of boxes and hitting delete

```
      }

  }


submit_delete();

mysqli_free_result($goodbye);
mysqli_close($dbc);


?>
```

Comment: So did you call `mysqli_error()` to see what the problem is? If it returns FALSE, there's a problem with your query, or you are not connected to your database.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the attribute `upload_id` of type `integer` in the database and not `varchar`?

Comment: I can't get any output with mysqli_error().  And pEkvo, upload_id is mediumint in my database - I'm thinking that this may be the issue

Comment: can you please provide sql query for $gone = "DELETE  FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN ("."$id_array".")"; after echo it on browser.

Comment: This is what is echoed after checking 2 boxes, the id's match the records from mysql database:  string(50) "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN (20,19)" bool(false) Error b/c delete failed. - Do I need to change my query to cast to an INT? The database field is mediumint and it autoincrements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.   I realized that during my haphazard development, I had created my database user with associated privileges BEFORE actually creating my uploads table.  I ran a grant permission statement on my database user and miraculously I am able to delete using the above code.  This also solved another issue I was having involving SESSION variables getting lost between pages.

This was an absolute nightmare - I hope this helps someone else as well.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
$id_array = implode(',',$id_array);        //-> You convert array into string.
//var_dump($id_array);
deleteUploads($id_array);                  //-> Call function for delete with string parameter.
```

Inside your delete function code you count string parameter ($id_array):

```
if (count($id_array) <= 0) { ...
```

cut your code from inside of delete function:

```
if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; echo 'wtf'; }
```

and insert before convert array into string:

```
$id_array = array_unique($id_array);
if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; echo 'wtf'; }
$id_array = implode(',',$id_array);
//var_dump($id_array);
deleteUploads($id_array);
```

Comment: I made this change. I am still unable to DELETE. I believe the problem lies with my database record for id being mediumint while my query is passing a string.

Comment: Ok try to change your delete query from:  $gone = "DELETE  FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN ("."$id_array".")"; into  $gone = "DELETE  FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN ({$id_array})";

Comment: This is my current DELETE query: $gone = "DELETE FROM upload WHERE upload_id IN ({$id_array})";     It is echoing the following to the screen: string(50) "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id` IN (20,19)" bool(false) Error b/c delete failed